# Using ssh private key on TortoiseGit

Tags: git, ssh, private-key, tortoisegit

I've created an ssh private key in one computer to use with TortoiseGit. Then I've sent my private key to my other computer, but I'm receiving an error message when I try to set my private key on Tortoise Git.

The error message is:

> Saving config failed (key: "remote.f1.puttykeyfile", value:
>   "D:\Documentos Ronaldo\ronaldo_private_key.ppk").

I already reinstalled TortoiseGit, but the problem remains. Do you know what can I do?

Comment: Is there anythink I can do to try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the problem doing a new clone and using ssh to get the new clone.